# How to embed video uploaded on google drive with restriction to specific domain

Tags: google-drive-api, embed

im trying to embed video uploaded to google drive in my website with code like this

```
 <iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B22NJzID0CU-QjZGdXp4OG1zNkq/preview" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

it woks perfectly but **i want to add some security/permission to it i want to allow only my Website domain (EX* www.XDomainX.com) to embed it** not to be embed on other sites
so how can i reach this?

i have read on google docs that i can set domain permission but it allows only user logged in with emails containing this domain to view the files and this is not the behavior i'm asking for

Answer (score 0):

Not possible without using OAuth2.0 and permissions.